# Invalid Identifier -- SQL compilation error with multiple joins

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run query with Multiple joins.

EX -

```
SELECT * FROM SC1.TABLE1 IHF
    JOIN SC1.TABL2 IAF ON IHF.COL1 = IAF.COL1
        AND IAF.COL2 = 'N'
        AND IAF.COL2 = 2001
        AND IHF.COL1 = 'N'
        AND IAF.COL2 = 2001
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SC1.TABL3 AID ON IAF.COL1 = AID.COL1
        AND AID.COL2 = 2001
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT COL1 AS ID,UPPER(TRIM(COL2)) FROM SC1.TABLE4 
        WHERE COL3 = 'ADV' AND COL4 = 2001)  AEM
        ON COALESCE((UPPER(TRIM(AID.COL3))),'') = UPPER(TRIM(AEM.COL3));
```

But after running 2nd left join it gives SQL compilation error -invalid identifier c.col1

First left join works but 2nd gives error

Comment: is the database MS-Sql-Server or Snowflake?

Comment: Trying in both as need to migrate code from SQL to Snowflake

Comment: the SQL grammars are rather different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in Snowflake, using some made up data in the CTE it runs just for me.

```
with table1(col1) as (
    select * from values
    (1),(2),(3)
), table2(col2) as (
    select * from values
    (1),(2),(3)
), table3(col1, col2) as (
    select * from values
    (1,''),(2,'not empty'),(3,'')
)
Select 
    a.col1,
    b.col2,
    c.col1 
from table1 a
join table2 b 
    ON a.col1 = b.col2
left outer join (
    select col1 from table3 where col2=''
)  c
  on a.col1 = c.col1;
```

gives me the result:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL1_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

can you provide better example data that triggers your problem, to scope your question better to which system (t-sql, snowflake) is giving you the problem, and again with what data.

### Code update:

So two problems I can see inside AEM you output two columns, the second has no alias/label, And in the ON clause AEM.col3 correctly does not exist. Nether you need to select that also so it can be used OR the second select was meant to be aliased to that.

but if I rewrite your SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ihf.*,
    iaf.*,
    aid.*,
    aem.id,
    aem.clean_col2
FROM sc1.table1 AS ihf
JOIN sc1.tabl2 AS iaf 
    ON ihf.col1 = iaf.col1
        AND iaf.col2 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
        AND ihf.col1 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
LEFT OUTER JOIN SC1.TABL3 AID 
    ON IAF.COL1 = AID.COL1
        AND AID.COL2 = 2001
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        COL1 AS ID,
        UPPER(TRIM(COL2)) as clean_col2,
        col3
    FROM SC1.TABLE4 
    WHERE COL3 = 'ADV' AND COL4 = 2001
)  AEM
    ON COALESCE((UPPER(TRIM(AID.COL3))),'') = UPPER(TRIM(AEM.COL3));
```

You can see I gave a name to the cleaned up col2 of `AEM`, but I would suggest you should move those "clean-ups" used in the ON into the related selects, so it can be a equi-join. But the join ON of IAF is broken as it stands:

```
JOIN sc1.tabl2 AS iaf 
    ON ihf.col1 = iaf.col1
        AND iaf.col2 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
        AND ihf.col1 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
```

how can `iaf.col2 = 'N'` AND `iaf.col2 = 2001` at which point I would guess that was a typo, and it should read

```
JOIN sc1.tabl2 AS iaf 
    ON ihf.col1 = iaf.col1
        AND iaf.col1= 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
        AND ihf.col1 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
```

but that feels somewhat redundant, but at least Snowflake should push the filters to the correct spot.

but really I would tend to write the code as, for performance reasons:

```
SELECT 
    ihf.*,
    iaf.*,
    aid.*, -- mimus clean_col3
    aem.id,
    aem.clean_col2
FROM sc1.table1 AS ihf
JOIN sc1.tabl2 AS iaf 
    ON ihf.col1 = iaf.col1
        AND iaf.col1 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
        AND ihf.col1 = 'N'
        AND iaf.col2 = 2001
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        COALESCE((UPPER(TRIM(col3))),'') AS clean_col3
    FROM sc1.tabl3
) AS aid 
    ON iaf.col1 = aid.col1
        AND aid.col2 = 2001
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        col1 AS id,
        UPPER(TRIM(col2)) AS clean_col2,
        UPPER(TRIM(aem.col3)) AS clean_col3
    FROM sc1.table4 
    WHERE col3 = 'ADV' AND col4 = 2001
)  AEM
    ON AID.clean_col3 = AEM.clean_col3;
```

Comment: SQL server solved with same query.
SNowflake still shows " SQL compilation error: error line 223 at position 69 invalid identifier c.col1"

Comment: @Rohan So you have some code atleast 200 lines long. Which the toy example code is not. So in a standard debugging your sql approach, I would start pruning you sql down to a bear minimum not-working example. Because the reason your 200 lines of sql is not working cannot be guessed at all from the 4 lines you have provided.

Comment: I have taken same 10 lines in another query and it gives same issue --SQL compilation error: error line 14 at position 68 invalid identifier. Not sure why its not taking the alias after 2nd left join ON condition

Comment: Yes. But if you cannot past the actual code (renamed all columns table etc etc) we cannot help find the problem.

Comment: updated can you pls check now and confirm

Comment: Can you pls help @simeon pilgrim

Comment: Thanks Simeon.  Alias for 2nd column was missing after giving that it worked fine.